# execute a python file globally from any path - windows7

Tags: python, windows, windows-7

I have a script `abc.py` under `C:\Python\Python35\Scripts\` folder and I have `C:\Python\Python35\python.exe;C:\Python\Python35\Scripts;C:\Python\Python35;` in my `PATH`. Still I'm not able to execute the python from anywhere else otherthan its directory.

For example, I always have to go to `C:Python\Python35\Scripts` and then execute `python abc.py`. Else, it is giving below error -

```
python: can't open file 'abc.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you associate .py files with python.exe? Then to start the script you just need its name (and no need to keep python folder in the path)

Comment: if you are not in folder with `abc.py` then you need full path to `abc.py` - ie. `python.exe  C:\Python\Python35\Scripts\abc.py`. Python doesn't use `PATH` to find script.

Comment: The default open action for .PY files should execute them using the py.exe launcher, in which case you can simply run `abc.py`. You can also add .PY to the `PATHEXT` environment variable, in which case you can simply run `abc`. If for some reason you can't or won't use the default file association, then in the cmd shell or a batch file you can use a for-loop variable to search `PATH`, e.g. `for %i in ("abc.py") do @python "%~$PATH:i"`.

Comment: I do have the file association and also have .py added to PATHEXTsystem path. 

If I just say C:\Users\mnr> abc.py, the file opens in a notepad. But if I say 
C:\Users\mnr>python abc.py , gets below error:

python: can't open file 'abc.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory 

My requirement is to be able to execute the python script from any path (not only from within the directory the python script is present)

Comment: .py files open in notepad, so obviously you've modified the default open action. I gave your the cmd shell code to use in a command prompt to search `PATH` using the special for-loop variable syntax `"%~$PATH:[for-loop variable]"`. It's not pretty, but it works. If you prefer to just run `abc`, then try the following to fix the file association: right-click a .py file; mouse over "Open with"; select "Choose another app"; select the "Python" icon with a rocket on it; select "Always use this app to open .py files"; and click "OK".

Comment: Thanks Eryksun! Executing the script as   `for %i in ("abc.py") do @python "%~$PATH:i"` worked fine. Is there a way to make this a global setting/add something inside the script itself so we can run directly abc.py on the command prompt?

Comment: When running `abc.py` directly cmd.exe calls the Windows `ShellExecuteEx` function, which uses the default or "open" action that was assigned by the user via the the "open with" dialog (as I described above) or control panel.

Comment: Ok, thanks @eryksun!